# How to disable a function to relaunch on hover

Tags: javascript, animation, hover, preventdefault

I'm trying to make a bouncy ball which move on hover by the user. I got a problem on how to disable the function to relaunch if the ball cross again the mouse. It cause some freeze/bugs sometimes. I'm not exactly sure on how to proceed to avoid that. Do you guys have any tips ?

https://codepen.io/kombolo/pen/YvzPvm

Thanks !

```
window.onmousemove = logMouseMove;

function logMouseMove(e) {
  e = e || window.event;    
  mousePos = e.clientX;
  el = document.querySelector('.circle');
  const elPos = getOffset(el);
  if(mousePos < (elPos -20) || mousePos > (elPos + 20)) {
     triggerAnimation(); 
  };  
}

function getOffset(el) {
  el = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return el.left + window.scrollX + 50;
}

function triggerAnimation() {
  xValues = [100, 0, 400];
  yValues = [0, 50, 200];
  const xVal = xValues[Math.floor(Math.random()*xValues.length)];
  const yVal = yValues[Math.floor(Math.random()*yValues.length)];
  var duration = anime({
    targets: '#duration .el',
    translateX: [
      { value: xVal, duration: 1000, delay: 500, elasticity: 0 },
      { value: xVal, duration: 1000, delay: 500, elasticity: 0 }
    ],
    scaleX: [
      { value: 2, duration: 100, delay: 500, easing: 'easeOutExpo' },
      { value: 1, duration: 900, elasticity: 300 },
      { value: 2, duration: 100, delay: 500, easing: 'easeOutExpo' },
      { value: 1, duration: 900, elasticity: 300 }
    ],
    translateY: [
      { value: yVal, duration: 1000, delay: 500, elasticity: 0 },
      { value: yVal, duration: 1000, delay: 500, elasticity: 0 }
    ],
  });


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Mouse hover is an extensive event. You are doing too much on hover.
what I would suggest is - set window.onmousemove = undefined in 
triggerAnimation function and then turn it on in the last. This helped a little.

function triggerAnimation() {
    window.onmousemove = void 0;

    xValues = [100, 0, 400];
    .....
    ....



    //loop: true
    });

    window.onmousemove = logMouseMove;
```

}

Comment: I see that anime returns an object where you can implement the begin and complete functions - you can try do this removing the event and attaching the event in those functions.